# Google analytics throw an error on ga.js:12

Tags: google-analytics

Somebody saw it...?

Uncaught TypeError: Object function (B){var A=this.indexOf(B);if(A!=-1){this.splice(A,1)}return this} has no method 'indexOf'

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Throws error for me as well. 
Also checked http://www.answers.com/ - ga.js throws error here too. It seems, that this error only occur when non-async setup is used for Google Analytics.

**UPDATE:** seems like they fixed it. Anyway it reminded me that i have to migrate to async setup.

**UPDATE #2:** problem still exists for me. As I understood, there is a two different versions of the script populated on Google's CDN, - one is faulty one, the other is okay. So sometimes it downloads proper script, sometimes it is not. I downloaded a 'proper' version and hosted it on our servers as temporarily solution.